# Sql Database Mirroring in a workgroup

Tags: sql, mirroring, workgroup

I found an article explaining almost everything I need to know here:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/kendalvandyke/2011/12/01/database-mirroring-in-a-windows-workgroup/

The only difference between my scenario and the one in the article is that I am using a witness.  That said, I'm wondering which service accounts should go in the Principal, Mirror, and Witness text boxes or if I will have to create the endpoints manually myself.  And if I will need to create them myself then I could use some help figuring out what the sql statements would need to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service accounts they are referring to are the accounts that the SQL database service is running.  In my experience I've never had to manually make the end points, but it's not difficult.

Here's the rundown on creating the endpoint:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181591.aspx

Comment: I just  noticed he put the principal account in the witness box and vice versa, explaining that this would create the endpoints so that they granted rights to account from the opposite machine.  I'm not sure how that works out when there are 3 machines involved (with the witness) though.

Comment: I think I understand what you're getting at, is there a reason that you aren't using certificates?  It looks like there's a few more steps but it should work, whereas this workaround only seems to work without a witness. Here's an overview of getting certificates set up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191477.aspx  You don't have to buy any certs, the server creates them and you have to share them with the other certificates.

Comment: Thanks, I just now saw your last comment but that's exactly what I ended up doing.